# MySQL stuck on "Repair by Sorting" (ENABLE KEYS)

Tags: mysql

I have a script that updates localhost, then dumps the updated results to remotehost:

```
mysqldump --skip-tz-utc --no-create-info --insert-ignore --host=localhost -u u -ppass db table --where=\"timeStamp > FROM_UNIXTIME( $time )\" | mysql -h remote -u u -ppass db
```

With 20 records, the update to localhost is very quick (a few seconds) but the dump to remotehost is taking over 4 minutes...when I look at mysql workbench, it says the state of remote host is "Repair by Sorting" and the Info column is "/*!40000 ALTER TABLE 'table' ENABLE KEYS */".

What does this message mean (and why is it taking so long to dump to remotehost with so few records)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysqldump` is disabling indexes, inserting the records, and re-enabling the indexes. This means it affects the entire table, including the many more records I expect are there based on the time.

Add `--skip-disable-keys` to the arguments for `mysqldump` and that should stop happening.

Comment: Depends on if you change triggers there and need them backed up. I'm guessing from your usage pattern that skipping triggers makes sense, but you'll have to look at the details of it yourself to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

The `mysqldump` command will do three things to a table during the reload:

1. `DISABLE KEYS`;
2. *multiple INSERTs*...
3. `ENABLE KEYS`;

When you disable keys, it actually disables non-unique indexes.

Primary Keys and Unique Keys are loaded immediately.

Once `ENABLE KEYS` is started, all non-unique indexes are then build using 'Repair By Sorting';

If you bypass `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS`, you will make things much worse, because the Primary Keys, Unique Keys, and Non-Unique Keys are built row by row and that's internally a messier operation for MySQL.

Since so little data is being added, doing `--skip-disable-keys` as 'Autocracy' suggested is both wise and concise.

BTW this only applies to MyISAM tables. InnoDB ignores `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS`.

Comment: I think you confused me more...you say if I bypass disable keys I will make things much worse but then tell me to do it 1 paragraph later. I've implemented Autocracy's solution....is that what I should do?

Comment: It would be much worse particularly if loading a large number of rows into an empty table with many indexes. By disabling keys to begin with and enabling them at the end, the process of building indexes, especially on a large number of rows inserted into an empty table, is optimized (you do it all once at the end, and there is no other data to worry about). However, lets say that you're inserting one row into 100 million, it's more efficient to rebalance the index on the fly for that one row than to drop it and create it from scratch... I think that's it anyway ;-)